# How to append and update new data to a SQL table without overwriting the old data?

Tags: sql, soql

Let's say we've got the following (very simplified compared to my real use case) table:

| Campaign ID | Campaign Name | Impressions | Clicks | Purchases |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111111 | Alfa | 5000 | 120 | 3 |
| 111112 | Beta | 7000 | 140 | 6 |
| 111113 | Gamma | 6000 | 90 | 3 |

With the usage of temporary SQL table we can pull out a new data for campaign Delta and also updated data for the ongoing campaign Gamma, but campaigns Alfa and Beta are historical and therefore not available in the temporary table and we want to leave them as they are.

New data pulled through a query could look like this:

| Campaign ID | Campaign Name | Impressions | Clicks | Purchases |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111113 | Gamma | 9000 | 160 | 7 |
| 111114 | Delta | 1000 | 40 | 0 |

How would I formulate a query that will bring me this result:

| Campaign ID | Campaign Name | Impressions | Clicks | Purchases |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111111 | Alfa | 5000 | 120 | 3 |
| 111112 | Beta | 7000 | 140 | 6 |
| 111113 | Gamma | 9000 | 160 | 7 |
| 111114 | Delta | 1000 | 40 | 0 |

I am sure this might be a common problem, but so far I wasn't able to find an easily understandable solution.

Apologies if this seems very simple.
And thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

1. Have one query that selects from the new table
2. Have another query that selects records from your old table that don't have the same keys as any records in your new table
3. UNION the two queries together